# How to install a 4 wire motion switch to a black and white wire system with no ground?

Tags: electrical

4 wire motion switch where do I hook the ground wire, if no ground wire from receptacle?

[image: bathroom switch black and white wire only]

Comment: Ground is not a problem, it grounds to the metal box. What kind of switch are you installing? Model#?

Comment: Ground is not needed for switches to work.  It is a nice safety factor for you only.  The white wire on the switch is not neutral.  It should be hot(but maybe switched hot), and should have black or red marking on it(tape/paint/ink).

Comment: You probably(99%) do not have the needed(4 wire) neutral in that box.  Without a re wire of that circuit, you might not be happy(have it work) with the new switch.  Neutral must be white.  White not always neutral.

Comment: Not enough information. This could be wired as two switch loops, or that second wire might use the power  from the first loop and provide a neutral from the second (wire at bottom). You need to know what each wire is set up to do. If the second wire is not being used, then it could provide the neutral. Need to check NEC and local codes for bringing this up to code. Running grounding wires might be required depending on changes made. For safety, a grounding wire should always be added when upgrading.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Metal boxes don’t magically provide ground. *Grounded* metal boxes provide ground. Connecting the switch’s ground wire to the pictured **ungrounded** box (supplied by ancient two-wire NM, no ground wires or conduit in sight) will accomplish nothing except give a false sense of security. The motion sensor might also not work if it powers itself by leaking a tiny bit of current to ground (to be usable in switch-loop no-neutral situations).

Comment: @nobody Which gets back to the rest of my comment: *What kind of switch are you installing? Model#?* It all depends on the specific model. If it *requires* ground then there must be a ground wire (or metal conduit) going back to the panel. But even if that is the case, unless instructions state otherwise it can still ground *yoke to metal box*, just the metal box then *must* be actually connected to ground. There is also a non-zero possibility (I found this in my own house) that the NM cable actually has a ground wire but that it is connected on the *outside* of the box instead of being

Comment: brought inside. In which case, it can be brought inside and connected properly and that solves that piece of the problem.  We need more details.